# How running JavaScript function in order?

Tags: javascript, html, css, async-await

**What am I doing?** 
I'm try running two function in order but JavaScript is calling and running two function in same time.

**What's the problem?** 
The `setModalBox` function give **undefined error** if is called before `setProjects` function.

**What have I already tried?** 
I tried used `Promise` with `setTimeout` it work, but can sometimes `setModalBox` function be called before and give of same error.

**Part of JavaScript:**

```js
class Portifolio{
  init() {
    this.setProjects();
    // this.setModalBox();
  }

  setProjects() {
    let response_promise = fetch("contents/projects.json")

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      response_promise.then(response => response.json().then(projects => {
        // ? Gradient in border for each color language

        for(let project in projects){
          // Div project
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.className = "project";
          div.id = `project-${projects[project].name}`
          document.querySelector(".projects").appendChild(div);

          // Tittle project
          var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
          h1.className = "tittle-project";
          h1.innerHTML = projects[project].name;
          document.querySelector(`#project-${projects[project].name}`).appendChild(h1);

          // Paragraph project
          var p = document.createElement("p");
          p.className = "about-project";
          p.innerHTML = projects[project].about;
          document.querySelector(`#project-${projects[project].name}`).appendChild(p);
        }
      }))
    }, false)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.setModalBox()
      }, Math.random() * 2000)
    })
  };

  setModalBox(){
    let projectsLength = document.querySelectorAll(".projects")[0].children.length;
    let modalBox = this.modalBox;

    for(let i = 0; i <= projectsLength; i++){
      let projectsAll = document.querySelectorAll(".projects")[0].children[i];

      // That "try" is for not to show error in console
      try{
        // Open Modal Box
        projectsAll.onclick = function(){
          modalBox.style.display = "block"
        };
      }catch{}

      // Close Modal Box, when click at "X"
      this.modalBoxClose.onclick = function(){
        modalBox.style.display = "None"
      };

      // Close Modal Box, when click out of Modal Box
      window.onclick = function(){
        if(event.target == modalBox){
          modalBox.style.display = "None"
        }
      }

      // Close Modal Box, when press esc key
      document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
        if(event.key == "Escape"){
          modalBox.style.display = "None"
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Projetos - Vitor Hugo's Portifolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div id="wrapperJS" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden">
      <nav>
        <a class="logo" href="/">Vitor Hugo</a>
        <div class="mobile-menu">
          <div class="line-1"></div>
          <div class="line-2"></div>
          <div class="line-3"></div>
        </div>
          <ul class="nav-list">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a href="projetos.html">Projetos</a></li>
            <li><a href="contatos.html">Contato</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <script src="mobile-screen.js"></script>

    <!-- Boxes -->
    <div class="projects"></div>

    <!-- Modal Boxes -->
    <div class="modal-box">
      <div class="modal-box-contents">
        <span class="modal-box-close">&times;</span>
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I have to do? please help me. If need more information,ask. And sorry for any error orthography and grammar I am studing English.

Comment: Why do you assign `this.modalBoxClose.onclick` and `window.onclick` in the loop? Those assignments don't use `projectsAll`, so they should only be done once.

Comment: `setProjects()` runs asynchronously. You need to call `setModalBox()` in its callback function. Or it should return a promise so you can call `setModalBox()` in its `.then()` method.

Comment: 1 option: Async/await for setProjects() function. 2 option: use callback

Answer (score 0):

Try async/await.
For example you can do it like this:

```
const setProjects = async () => {
try {
await // Put your code here
}catch (err){
console.log(err)
}
};
```

Then :

```
setProjects().then(setModalBox());
```

Now your functions will be executed in an order.

Comment: That functions is inside a class, so when I use a const function it give that error: A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `setModalBox` at the end of the DOMContentLoaded event handler.